# Quarkus compilation native fails with flyway

Tags: java, quarkus, flyway, graalvm

I have this error but I cannot found any information about this:

```
2022-09-20 09:48:36,035 ERROR [io.qua.run.Application] (main) Failed to start application (with profile prod): java.lang.IllegalStateException: 'org.flywaydb.core.internal.scanner.Scanner' is never used in Quarkus
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.scanner.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:27)
        at org.flywaydb.core.FlywayExecutor.createResourceAndClassProviders(FlywayExecutor.java:252)
        at org.flywaydb.core.FlywayExecutor.execute(FlywayExecutor.java:135)
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:124)
```

I'm pretty sure that the sql migration files are included with the compilation with the parameter "quarkus.native.resources.includes=db/migration/**".

Somebody have an idea that what is happening?

**Versions:**
Version info: 'GraalVM 22.1.0 Java 11 CE'
Quarkus 2.10.1

**Compilation with maven:**

```
mvn clean package -Dnative
```

I had testing also with versions of Quarkus 2.12.2.Final and 2.13.0.CR1 with the same results.

Comment: Does the same problem occur with Quarkus `2.12.2.Final` and / or `2.13.0.CR1`?

Comment: Could you see if this is similar https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/10716

Comment: No, is different issue.

Comment: With 2.12.2.Final of Quarkus I have the same error.

Comment: @Eusebio have you fixed that error? I am also facing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar or maybe the same issue and found a solution here https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/10716#issuecomment-1069943206. So in my issue I was creating a Flyway instance programmatically `(Flyway.flyway())` and calling `migrate()`. This instantiation was the issue for me. Retrieving it via `arc` solved the issue. Since this is the number 1 thread to find when searching for this issue I'll leave this here.

```
QuarkusPathLocationScanner.setApplicationMigrationFiles(files);
DataSource ds = Flyway.configure().dataSource("jdbc:" + datasourceUrl, datasourceUsername, datasourcePassword).getDataSource();
FlywayContainerProducer flywayProducer = Arc.container().instance(FlywayContainerProducer.class).get();
 FlywayContainer flywayContainer = flywayProducer.createFlyway(ds, "<default>", true, true);
 Flyway flyway = flywayContainer.getFlyway();
 flyway.migrate();
```